# Custom routing for forms action

Tags: zend-framework, routes

I want to make routing for form when submitting the form,

```
 $reportRoute = new Zend_Controller_Router_Route('blogsedit/blog_id/:blog_id', array('module' => 'blogs', 'controller' => 'blog', 'action' => 'edit','blog_id' =>NULL));

$routesArray = array('blogs' => $reportRoute);

$router->addRoutes($routesArray);
```

and in the form I used to make like this

```
<form action="/blogs/blog/edit/blog_id/<?php echo $blogId?>"

</form>
```

How can I make the custom routing of the form action ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [view helper `url()`](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.view.helpers.html#zend.view.helpers.initial).

> **url($urlOptions, $name, $reset)**: Creates a URL string based on a named
>   route. $urlOptions should be an associative array of key/value pairs
>   used by the particular route.
>
> - Generates an url given the name of a route.
> - @access public
> - @param  array $urlOptions Options passed to the assemble method of the Route object.
> - @param  mixed $name The name of a Route to use. If null it will use the current Route
> - @param  bool $reset Whether or not to reset the route defaults with those provided
> - @return string Url for the link href attribute.

In your case, you would have something like:

```
url(array('blog_id' => $blogId), 'blogs', true)
```

Comment: How can I get the value of the url parameter in .PHTML pages?? I want to add it to the form action url, $_GET doesn't work!

Comment: You either pass it to the view using `$this->view->blogId = $this->_getParam('blogId');` or you set your form action directly in your controller with `$form->setAction();`

Comment: I solve it through making action="<?php echo $this->url() ?>" by this way I get the current URL